# Catching warnings pre-python 2.6

Tags: python, warnings, suppress-warnings

In Python 2.6 it is possible to suppress warnings from the warnings module by using

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

Versions of Python before 2.6 don't support `with` however, so I'm wondering if there alternatives to the above that would work with pre-2.6 versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar:

```
# Save the existing list of warning filters before we modify it using simplefilter().
# Note: the '[:]' causes a copy of the list to be created. Without it, original_filter
# would alias the one and only 'real' list and then we'd have nothing to restore.
original_filters = warnings.filters[:]

# Ignore warnings.
warnings.simplefilter("ignore")

try:
    # Execute the code that presumably causes the warnings.
    fxn()

finally:
    # Restore the list of warning filters.
    warnings.filters = original_filters
```

**Edit:** Without the `try/finally`, the original warning filters would not be restored if fxn() threw an exception. See [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for more discussion on how the `with` statement serves to replace `try/finally` when used like this.

Comment: Morgoth: It makes a copy of the filters, modifies them, calls fxn, and finally resets the filters to the original value. Pretty much the exact same thing the 2.6 context manager does.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - why is the try ... finally needed?

Comment: I've added comments to explain the code and a note about why the try ... finally is better.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on what the minimum version you need to support using Python 2.5's

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

might be an option, else you'll probably need to fallback to what Jon suggested.

Comment: As Pär Wieslander pointed out to me when I tried this answer (which I now see I shouldn't have deleted), `catch_warnings()` was introduced in 2.6, so in this case, just having the with statement doesn't help (unless you want to copy the implementation of `catch_warnings()`.